# Locating a schema that owns a role

Tags: sql, oracle, oracle11g, role

Let's say we've logged on under the A schema.

I am able to execute the following statement

```
grant select on wph_pden to LANDING_R;
```

However, the LANDING_R object can not be located in the schema A. It is absent from all the system tables and views.

How do I find out which schema owns the LANDING_R (which I know is a role, not user)???

Comment: Although there is a 1:1 relation between user and schema in Oracle, there is a difference between them. Roles are granted to users, not schemas. An one usually speaks of logging in "as a user" not "under a schema".

Comment: thanks a lot, will take this into consideration

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Have you tried searching for role as `SYSDBA`?
You can list all the roles existing in the database with `DBA_ROLES` or `DBA_TAB_PRIVS`

```
select grantee from dba_role_privs where granted_role='LANDING_R'
```

Comment: Is there a way to find out which user created a particular role?